# Assign values to Multiple rows pandas columns with same rows same value

Tags: python, group-by

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C','B','A','B']})
```

I will like to get something like this where Col2 does not consider alphabetical order but the order text appear

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C','B','A','B'],
                   'Col2': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3]})
```

I have tried something like this

```
df['Col2'] =df.groupby(['Col1']).ngroup()
```

what i get is different from my expected output. see result of the above code

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| C | 2 |
| A | 0 |
| C | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `sort` option to your groupby because by default `groupby` will `sort`

```
df['val'] = df.groupby(by='Col1', sort=False).ngroup()+1
```

This should solve your question